# How to get rid of the white background of Choropleth?

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly

I am building a dashboard using Potly Dashboard. I am using a dark bootstrap theme therefore I don't want a white background.

However, my map now looks like this:

[image: my map]

And the code that produced it is shown below:

```
trace_map = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(
            id = "map",
            figure = go.Figure(
                data=go.Choropleth(
                locations=code, # Spatial coordinates
                z = df.groupby(['month']).sum()['Sales'].astype(int), 
                locationmode = 'USA-states',
                colorscale = 'Reds',
                colorbar_title = "USD",
            ), layout = go.Layout(title = 'The Cities Sold the Most Product',
                                  font = {"size": 9, "color":"White"},
                                  titlefont = {"size": 15, "color":"White"},
                                  geo_scope='usa',
                                  margin={"r":0,"t":40,"l":0,"b":0},
                                  paper_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  plot_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  )
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

I have tried `paper_bgcolor`, and `plot_bgcolor` but couldn't make it work.

Ideally I would like to achieve how this image looks (please ignore the red dots):
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally:

```
fig.update_layout(geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
```

And in your specific example:

```
go.Layout(geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig  = go.Figure(
                data=go.Choropleth(
                #locations=code, # Spatial coordinates
                #z = df.groupby(['month']).sum()['Sales'].astype(int), 
                locationmode = 'USA-states',
                colorscale = 'Reds',
                colorbar_title = "USD",
            ), layout = go.Layout(geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'),
                                  title = 'The Cities Sold the Most Product',
                                  font = {"size": 9, "color":"White"},
                                  titlefont = {"size": 15, "color":"White"},
                                  geo_scope='usa',
                                  margin={"r":0,"t":40,"l":0,"b":0},
                                  paper_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  plot_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  )
            )

fig.show()
```

And you might want to change the color of the lakes too. But do note that setting `lakecolor =  'rgba(0,0,0,0)'` will give the lakes the same color as the states and not the bakground. So I'd go with `lakecolor='#4E5D6C'`. You could of course do the same thing with `bgcolor`, but setting it to `'rgba(0,0,0,0)'` gets ***rid*** of the white color which you specifically asked for.

**Lake color plot:**

[image]

**Lake color code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig  = go.Figure(
                data=go.Choropleth(
                #locations=code, # Spatial coordinates
                #z = df.groupby(['month']).sum()['Sales'].astype(int), 
                locationmode = 'USA-states',
                colorscale = 'Reds',
                colorbar_title = "USD",
            ), layout = go.Layout(geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', lakecolor='#4E5D6C'),
                                  title = 'The Cities Sold the Most Product',
                                  font = {"size": 9, "color":"White"},
                                  titlefont = {"size": 15, "color":"White"},
                                  geo_scope='usa',
                                  margin={"r":0,"t":40,"l":0,"b":0},
                                  paper_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  plot_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  )
            )

fig.show()
```

And we could just as well change the state border colors, or what is more cryptically known as `subunitcolor` in this context. And to better match your desired endresult we could spice up the landcolor as well:

**State border and state colors, plot:**

[image]

**State border and state colors, code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig  = go.Figure(
                data=go.Choropleth(
                #locations=code, # Spatial coordinates
                #z = df.groupby(['month']).sum()['Sales'].astype(int), 
                locationmode = 'USA-states',
                colorscale = 'Reds',
                colorbar_title = "USD",
            ), layout = go.Layout(geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', lakecolor='#4E5D6C',
                                          landcolor='rgba(51,17,0,0.2)',
                                          subunitcolor='grey'),
                                  title = 'The Cities Sold the Most Product',
                                  font = {"size": 9, "color":"White"},
                                  titlefont = {"size": 15, "color":"White"},
                                  geo_scope='usa',
                                  margin={"r":0,"t":40,"l":0,"b":0},
                                  paper_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  plot_bgcolor='#4E5D6C',
                                  )
            )

fig.show()
```

Comment: Great! thank you, but I have no idea where i should put this snippet in. would you please tell? Because i tried putting geo in go.Layout, but it shows error.

Comment: @yts61 I haven't used `dcc.Graph` much myself. But it should work just fine if you put `geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')` into your `go.Layout` definition.

Answer (score 1):

I found my way here because I wanted to change the theme of my Choroplethmapbox.  The accepted solution helped, but ultimately I found the code below worked for my situation:

## instantiate figure

```
fig = go.Figure()
```

## add some traces

```
fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=data_for_choropleth_geojson, 
                                  locations=data_for_choropleth['fips'],
                                  z=data_for_choropleth['total_population'],
                                  featureidkey='properties.fips'
                              ))
```

## finally, change the theme using update_layout

```
fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
                # style options: "basic", "streets", "outdoors", 
                # "dark", "satellite", or "satellite-streets","light"
                # "open-street-map", "carto-positron", 
                # "carto-darkmatter", "stamen-terrain", 
                # "stamen-toner" or "stamen-watercolor"
                style='light',
                bearing=0,
                pitch=0,
                accesstoken=TOKEN,
                zoom=5,
                center=dict(
                    lat=29.4652568,
                    lon=-98.613121
        )
)
```